# CRT monitor SMART protection capability

Tags: crt

In this wiki page:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer

There is something called "SMART" protection capability to avoid monitor to driven 
it's hardware capabilities.

> An unfortunate side-effect of this method was that the display device could be driven beyond its capabilities. In some cases this resulted in hardware damage to the display.[6] More commonly, it simply produced garbled and unusable output. Modern CRT monitors fix this problem through the introduction of "smart" protection circuitry. When the display mode is changed, the monitor attempts to obtain a signal lock on the new refresh frequency. If the monitor is unable to obtain a signal lock, or if the signal is outside the range of its design limitations, the monitor will ignore the framebuffer signal and possibly present the user with an error message.

How this works? Can anybody give me the mechanism behind this.
I need to study a schematic which does implement this "SMART" protection capability.
I have searched for the specification on google, but I didn't found it.
How could I one implement this feature on a industrial CRT?

Comment: In the quoted sentence, I think "smart" just means "slightly more complicated, sophisticated and well designed than what we had ten years ago" - "smart" isn't the *name* of a specific technology (unlike say [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)). It's still an interesting question though.

Comment: It's not a given that this must be implement in a microcontroller; a voltage controlled oscillator in a PLL, or a PLL loop itself, could be designed with approximate minimum/maximum frequency limits.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "smart" simply means that there's a microcontroller with firmware that monitors and validates the signals coming into the monitor. This microcontroller also manages the user interface of the monitor itself, and generates the on-screen menus, status messages, etc.

Comment: with a on screen display chip? So what I have to review is schematic the MCU part and on screen display chip part ?
It does try to sync and then ?